# Using gitlab CI yaml with multiline bash command (e.g curl with a json header)

Tags: json, curl, yaml, gitlab-ci.yml

Sometimes I struggle at the most stupid places.. But how can I issue a multiline curl from gitlab ci's yaml file? I tried the following:

```
curl --request POST \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" \
    --data "{ \
      \"name\": \"$CI_PROJECT_NAME\", \
    }" \
    "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/releases"
```

Which yields:

```
An error has occurred and reported in the system's low-level error handler.
```

Now I think this is more bash specific, so I tried to use single quotes:

```
  curl --request POST \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN' \
    --data '{
      "name": "$CI_PROJECT_NAME"
    }' \
    "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/releases"
```

That works (well it gives me a server response that is) but bash will now take the variables literally, so $CI_JOB_TOKEN is not replaced, also not $CI_PROJECT_NAME.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
  script:
    - >
      curl --fail -X "POST"
      "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/releases"
      -H "Content-Type: application/json"
      -H "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN"
      --data '{
        "name": "$CI_PROJECT_NAME"
      }'
```

Comment: But that doesn't work for said reason: The $CI_PROJECT_NAME is not replaced within single quotes ' '', because everything is taken as a literal

Answer (score 0):

Found quite a nice workaround using envsubst:

```
  script:
    - >
      echo '{
          "name": "will be replaced -> ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}",
          "tag_name": "v0.6",
          "description": "Super nice release",
          "ref": "master",
          "assets": {
            "links": [{
              "name": "hoge",
              "url": "https://google.com",
              "direct_asset_path": "/binaries/linux-amd64",
              "link_type":"other"
            }]
          }
        }' > payload.json
    - |
      curl \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" \
        --data "$(cat payload.json | envsubst)" \
        --request POST "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/releases"
```

Just add `apk add gettext` to your alpine image